# Is it possible to trigger an event across two backbone views?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

If I have two views on one page, how can I go about triggering an event with $.trigger() in one view and capturing that event in another?

Comment: Why don't you trigger the event on a separate object and have both views listen to that object (you might want to also use the  backbone [events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) module)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're relying on DOM events for communication between your views then you run the risk that it stops working if you change the structure of your application since DOM events only bubble upwards in the tree.

It's easier to have a dedicated event channel for the entire application that the two views both can access.

Backbone comes with an [event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) implementation that you can use for this.

eventChannel:

```
var eventChannel = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

view1:

```
this.listenTo(eventChannel, 'myEvent', function(args) { ... });
```

view2:

```
eventChannel.trigger('myEvent', ...);
```

You can attack data to the event when calling `trigger` and it will be passed on to the event handler. By using `listenTo` you allow the view to keep track of its listeners so they can be cleaned up when the view is removed. The callback function will be called with the listener as context, so in the callback `this` will be the view that was listening.